# Arrayformula to index, match row values to the column title and an error checking row

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

In [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10U4BrL-wFZyil7VZko8pq4KuHhNaqAO61ZS-qgj1VMc/edit?usp=sharing)

Columns `D` and `E` reference the column “title” (row 2, `J2:M2`). If the respective value in row `F` is `>0`, the value in `D` is “Bank Account” and the value in `E` is the column title (`J5:M5`). (Vice-versa for `E`, negative is “Bank Account”

Column `H` gives the difference from column `F` to the analysis in cols `J` to `M`

Column `I` gives an Error Check, for various if conditions.

**I am looking for: An array formula which replaces this index(match formula, in cols `D` and `E`, replaces the sum formula in col `H` and makes the Error if statements work in col `I`. So that if new data is added the formula will automatically work without having to be copied down into the new rows.**

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use MAP surely in every case, just replace the cells of the same row with variables. For example:

```
=MAP(A6:A,B6:B,F6:F,G6:G,H6:H,J6:J,LAMBDA(a,b,f,g,h,j,IF(AND(a="",b="",f=""),"No Error",IF(COUNT(J6:6)>1,"Multiple Analyses given on one row, please limit one analysis per individual row",                                                                                                                                       IF(AND(a<>"",f=""),"Amount required (column F)",IF(AND(a="",g<>""),"Date Required (Column A)",IF(h<>0,"<-- Sum Difference","No Error")))))
```

Comment: Thanks @Martín, I have had a go and struggling to get it working. I have duplicated the sheet. Would you kindly edit cols D, E, H and I in the duplicate to show me how this is done. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also I’m afraid this formula doesn’t work. If there is an error in one row, it states there is an error in every row. :/